# List of generated event listeners only triggers last one

Tags: javascript, select, for-loop, onchange

Here is the full code for demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/DF2Uw/4/

Basically, I generate multiple event listeners with a `FOR` loop. I generate multiple `<selects>` and want to detect the onChange event and return the ID of the specific select that was changed. However it seems only the last eventlistener survives as the others do no trigger.

Any explanation for this behavior?

HTML

```
<ol id="slots"></ol>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var slotnameHtml = '';
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i += 1) {
    var slotname = document.createElement('select'),
        slottime = document.createElement('select'),
        slotlist = document.createElement('li');
    slotname.innerHTML = slotnameHtml;
    slottime.innerHTML = '<optgroup><option value="1">00:01</option><option value="2">00:02</option></optgroup>';
    slottime.id='test'+i;
    slotlist.appendChild(slotname);
    slotlist.appendChild(slottime);
    document.getElementById('slots').appendChild(slotlist);
    slottime.addEventListener('change', function () {
        alert(slottime.id)
    });;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the handlers you bind to `change` do not run immediately, but later. In the meantime, your `for` loop has run its course and `slottime` has been rebound to its final value (the last `<select>` element you created). All the handlers will only see that value.

You can introduce a closure in order for the right elements to be accessible to the handlers:

```
document.getElementById("slots").appendChild(slotlist);
(function(slottime) {
    slottime.addEventListener("change", function() {
        alert(slottime.id);
    });
})(slottime);
```

As Teemu righfully says in the comments, the simplest solution is to take advantage of the fact that `this` is bound to the target element inside the handler:

```
slottime.addEventListener("change", function() {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Comment: Would it be a lot more simpler just to use `this.id` in the event handler function?

Comment: @Teemu, yes, but doing that would not explain the root problem to the questioner :) I'll add it to my answer, though.

Comment: I'm not quite familiar with closures so will do some research :). But the code seems to work. Thanks a lot!

Comment: why are you using this here ??..what this corresponds ..which globalobject ? is it slottime ?..

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the following alert parameter insted:

```
alert(this.getAttribute('id'));
```

Comment: why are you using this here ??..what this corresponds ..which globalobject ? is it slottime ?

Comment: When you call the function it will use the value of variable slottime at the moment of the call of the function and not at the time of creation... You have to take the id of the elements that call the function and for do that you should use this

Comment: Correspond to the element that invokes the function, if you open the development tool of your browser and you inspect the element you can see the id of the element

Comment: You are not answering the question properly brother ..I asked in this case is $this corresponds to varibale slottime..Here slottime invokes the function...

Comment: There is no variable $this, there is $(this) that return the jQuery element that correspond to the invoking element

Comment: i asked is "this" corresponds to variable slottime here ??.

Comment: Yes, the variable slottime at the moment of creation