# adding event listeners with list.forEach() - only last list item changes

Tags: javascript, event-handling, interactive

I'm new to webdesign (and coding) and this afternoon I bumped into a problem I can't solve alone. I hope one of you could help me.

I want to create text elements that change to green when a user hovers over it with her mouse, and to red when the mouse goes out again. (Later, audio files will start to play when a mouse hovers over a specific object.)
When you run the code, you can see that only the last element changes to red, also when a mouse hovers over the other elements. What is wrong with my (Javascript) code?

```js
const elements = [
    {title: 'Element1'},
    {title: 'Element2'},
    {title: 'Element3'},
    {title: 'Element4'},
    {title: 'Element5'}
];

window.onload = () => {
    elements.forEach(element => {
        title = document.getElementById(element.title);
        //add event listeners
        title.addEventListener("mouseover", handleMouseOver = () => {
            mouseOver(title);
        });
        title.addEventListener("mouseout", handleMouseOut = () => {
            mouseOut(title);
        });
    });
};

//play soundfiles
const mouseOver = (title) => {
    title.style.backgroundColor = "red";
};
const mouseOut = (title) => {
    title.style.backgroundColor = "#4CAF50";
};
```

```css
body {
    margin:0;
          margin-left:0em;
          padding:0;
          overflow: hidden;
      }
      canvas {
          margin:auto;
      }

.compositions {
    display: inline-block;
    align-items: center;
    font-style: arial;
    font-size: 17px;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5em;
}
.compositions p {
    margin-bottom: 0.8em;
    margin:0em 0.8em 1em 1em;
    display: inline-block;
}

.compositions input {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    border-radius:50px;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.compositions p:hover{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>InteractiveWebsite</title>

    <script src="../libraries/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="../libraries/p5.dom.js"></script>
    <script src="../libraries/p5.sound.js"></script>
    <!--script src="../libraries/Tone.js"></script-->
    <!--CreateJS libraries-->
    <script src="../libraries/soundjs.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../libraries/cordovaaudioplugin.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../libraries/flashaudioplugin.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../libraries/preloadjs.min.js"></script>
    <!--Own javascript files-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="compositions">
            <p id=Element1>Element 1</p><br>
            <p id=Element2>Element 2</p><br>
            <p id=Element3>Element 3</p><br>
            <p id=Element4>Element 4</p><br>
            <p id=Element5>Element 5</p><br>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
    <noscript>Sorry, your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

I looked into two other topics ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33413958/dynamic-event-listener-working-only-on-the-last-created-element) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22966135/list-of-generated-event-listeners-only-triggers-last-one)), but they didn't seem applicable for my situation.

Thanks in advance,
Mustard Shaper

Comment: `title` is a global variable because it's not declared, declare it first like so: `let title = ...`

Comment: BTW, why are you using 2 functions for each event, just make `mouseOver` and `mouseOut` a regular function (for example `const mouseOver = function() { this.style... }`) so you can use `this` inside, and pass that directly to `addEventListener` like so: `title.addEventListener("mouseover", mouseOver);`, the `this` will refer to the element that triggered the event. Do the same to `mouseOut`

Comment: Unfortunately, declaring the variables didn't solve nor change the code. Could there be another problem or solution? Thanks for the second comment, that's more logical indeed.

Comment: declaring the variable does fix the problem, I've just tried it and it works. Can you check again? `title = document.getElementById(element.title);` should become `let title = document.getElementById(element.title);`

Comment: Ah, you're right! I'm sorry, I checked in my expanded code, there it doesn't solve the problem. But then something else must be the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You face a closure problem, title is not declared

```
window.onload = () => {
    elements.forEach(element => {
        title = document.getElementById(element.title);
        //add event listeners
        title.addEventListener("mouseover", handleMouseOver = () => {
            mouseOver(title);
        });
        title.addEventListener("mouseout", handleMouseOut = () => {
            mouseOut(title);
        });
    });
}
```

So the 'default declaration' seems to be outside of the forEach. Just declare it like `const title = document.getElementById(element.title);` and everything will work.

Also add quote to id attribute like

```
            <p id='Element1'>Element 1</p><br>
```

This is not part of your bug but just a small mistake

**Edition**

As you can see, it works

```js
const elements = [
    {title: 'Element1'},
    {title: 'Element2'},
    {title: 'Element3'},
    {title: 'Element4'},
    {title: 'Element5'}
];

window.onload = () => {
    elements.forEach(element => {
        const title = document.getElementById(element.title);
        //add event listeners
        title.addEventListener("mouseover", handleMouseOver = () => {
            mouseOver(title);
        });
        title.addEventListener("mouseout", handleMouseOut = () => {
            mouseOut(title);
        });
    });
};

//play soundfiles
const mouseOver = (title) => {
    title.style.backgroundColor = "red";
};
const mouseOut = (title) => {
    title.style.backgroundColor = "#4CAF50";
};
```

```css
body {
    margin:0;
          margin-left:0em;
          padding:0;
          overflow: hidden;
      }
      canvas {
          margin:auto;
      }

.compositions {
    display: inline-block;
    align-items: center;
    font-style: arial;
    font-size: 17px;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5em;
}
.compositions p {
    margin-bottom: 0.8em;
    margin:0em 0.8em 1em 1em;
    display: inline-block;
}

.compositions input {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    border-radius:50px;
    color: white;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-style: arial;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.compositions p:hover{
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>InteractiveWebsite</title>

    <script src="../libraries/p5.js"></script>
    <script src="../libraries/p5.dom.js"></script>
    <script src="../libraries/p5.sound.js"></script>
    <!--script src="../libraries/Tone.js"></script-->
    <!--CreateJS libraries-->
    <script src="../libraries/soundjs.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../libraries/cordovaaudioplugin.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../libraries/flashaudioplugin.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../libraries/preloadjs.min.js"></script>
    <!--Own javascript files-->

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <main>
        <div class="compositions">
            <p id='Element1'>Element 1</p><br>
            <p id='Element2'>Element 2</p><br>
            <p id='Element3'>Element 3</p><br>
            <p id='Element4'>Element 4</p><br>
            <p id='Element5'>Element 5</p><br>
        </div>
    </main>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
    <noscript>Sorry, your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Dear Farvilain, thanks for the quick answer! I changed the code according to your suggestion, however, it didn't solve the problem. The words keep acting the same way.

Comment: I added a snippet with correction, as you can see everything works

Comment: You're correct, my bad! I was working in my expanded code where it didn't change, but something else must be the problem there.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you need to play audio files later, but that is an awful lot of work when you could probably just [solve the problem with CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover). In general, you don't want to do with JavaScript what you can do with CSS. Save JavaScript for things you can't do with CSS.

```css
p {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
p:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Hi brokenindexfinger! Since I'll add more code later - most particularly code for sound files that will start playing once a mouse hovers over a text object - css is not the solution. This example was just a simplified version of my code in fuction of the debugging.